# Creating a variable in a string

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a variable withing a variable value in php?
I am trying to create a php function that writes html attributes

```
$code = '$query = "SQL Query"'
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it a good idea? No, it's a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Processing it will require `eval()` which opens up significant attack vectors.

Comment: As Alex says, `eval()` is what you are looking for but also a very bad idea. Maybe you should explain what you are looking for exactly. What goes into the function and what needs to come out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
$code = 'query';
$$code = '"SQL Query"';

echo $query; // outputs: "SQL Query"
```

Its called the variable variable and you can read mora about it in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)